# Apache set specific PHP binary

Tags: php, apache

I have googled this and found lots of hits which appeared to be the same as I was asking but turned out not to be.

I have 2 different versions of PHP installed, and I would like to specify exactly which php binary apache uses when it starts up.

How could this be done?

Comment: The one with php.ini in the right directory.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example to indicate version 5.3 should be used and the route to php.ini. Add the following lines to .htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php53 .php
SuPHP_ConfigPath /PathTo/DirWithPHP.ini
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have a machine where php runs as a cgi. I just keep multiple separate installs. Apache looks in `/ws/php` for the binary

```
/ws/php
/ws/php5.3
/ws/php5.4
/ws/php5.5
```

switching versions is a simple folder rename.

There's other ways, but this works and is very simple.